# Trouble in overriding the equals(...) method in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have a superclass `Order` which has a subclass `OrderBook`. The `equals(...)` method is overridden in the `OrderBook`. The method implementation is as follows:-

```
public boolean equals(Order o)
    {
        if(o==null){
            System.out.println("object is null.");
            return false;
        }
        if(o==this){
            System.out.println("The object is itself.");
            return true;
        }
        if(o instanceof OrderBook)
        {
            OrderBook o1 = (OrderBook)o;
            if(!(o1.productId.equals(productId))){
                System.out.println("productId mismatch.");
                return false;
            }
            if(!(o1.customerId.equals(customerId))){
                System.out.println("customerId mismatch.");
                return false;
            }
            if(o1.book!=book){
                System.out.println("book mismatch.");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I am encountering an unexpected output if I give the following statement:-

```
Order order1 = new OrderBook("Algorithms","Kunal",false);
Order order2 = new OrderBook("Algorithms","Kunal",false);
System.out.println(order1.equals(order2));
```

It should display `true` but its displaying `false`. Also, if I change the parameter in the `equals(...)` to `Object o`, then the whole program runs without any problem.

My doubt is that why are we using `Object` when we should be using `Order`?

Comment: You are actually not overriding `equals`. Because `equals` from Object class has different signature. `public boolean equals(Object o)`

Comment: If you are overriding, you are overring the parent method. This is method overloading what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public boolean equals(Order o)
```

Should be

```
public boolean equals(Object o)
```

**Explanation**

This is because you're attempting to override a method. When you override a method, you need to match the signature *exactly*. The signature is made up of:

- The name of the method
- **The type of the arguments**
- The number of arguments
- The return type.

The type of the argument in the original method signature was `Object`, yet you've provided an object of type `Order`. Hence, the runtime will treat these are two distinct methods.

Comment: Thanks. But when I give the statement 
`Order order1 = new OrderBook("Algorithms","Kunal",false);`
`Order order2 = order1;`
`System.out.println(order1.equals(order2));`

Why do I get a true?

Comment: Have you changed the method signature to match `equals(Object o)`? And if you have, you're passing the same object to the `equals` method, and in your code, you state that if the object is the same, print out "Same object" and return `true`.

Comment: No. This is before I changed the parameter to `Object o`.

Comment: You're calling your new `equals` method, since the overload can be resolved directly to `equals(Order)`, but none of the other Java utilities that depend on `equals` -- `HashSet` and friends in particular -- will use your new `equals` method.

Answer (score 1):

try putting this instead of your block in the books comparing part

```
if(!o1.book.equals(book)){
      System.out.println("book mismatch.");
      return false;
}
```

And change the signature it should be equals(Object o)
Also do not forget the @Override annotation

Answer (score 1):

To override a method in Java, you must match its signature exactly. The signature of [`Object#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) is:

```
public boolean equals(Object o)
```

a fairly standard approach is to overriding equals is:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (obj == this)
        return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof Order))
        return false;

    // specific comparisons for your Order object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone did a good job explaning how to make it work. I want to explain why your's didnt work: (pay close attention to the type of parameter in equals())

Object class has equals(Object ojb). When JVM encounters the statement "order1.equals(order2)" it says to itself: Hmmmm ... order is of type Order and references OrderBook. I need to use the overriden equals() method if OrderBook has one. Dang!! OrderBook doesnt have equals(Object) instead it has equals(Order). So Im going to use equals(Object) from Object class.

What you have is called OVERLOADING. not overriding.